# In Twitter API How to check a tweet has been deleted on twitter if I check it via a Tweet id saved in my database

Tags: twitter

I have used Twitter API for fetching the tweets with a particular hash tag and all the data stored in my database.

I am currently working in core PHP.

API is working fine, thanks to Twitter

Now problem comes with the deleted tweets, Actually when a record of 100 latest tweets comes on my ajax file directly I store them in my database with a flag visible="y" . Now I want that if any of tweet stored in my database is being deleted from responsive twitter account automatically set visible = "N" into my database.

I searched a lot on internet but I could not find any respected answer.
Please reply me and ask me if any further information is needed.

Thanks to Stack Overflow for a good community.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to do what you're suggesting, is to run some process that reads the tweets from your database and checks to see if they are still there.

You can call https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/lookup.json and pass it a comma-delimited list of 100 tweets, and then compare the return value to your database to see if the tweets you asked for are still available or not.

You will have to iterate through your database 100 tweets at a time.  Depending on how many tweets you are storing, you may run into rate limit issues.

Comment: But don't you think it will increase my database fetching and decrease my project speed since suppose I have stored 2000 records in my database and Now I am fetching 100 records from Twitter and matching them to my database for checking the currently undeleted tweets, so with in a limited time I have to check that how many tweets are live or not.


Any modification in my answer will be welcomed.

Comment: Yes it will, but there's no easy way around it.  The question you might want to ask is: "Do I really need to know whether or not a tweet is deleted?"  Tweets are created and disseminated so quickly that deleting a tweet is almost pointless.  Why do you need to know if a tweet was deleted?

Comment: Actually I am showing latest 100 tweets on my website front page and suppose after 2 hours there is no new tweets and from 100 earlier records 5 tweets are deleted but I have saved that records in my database.
Accordingly If a tweet which is in my database if it is being deleted from twitter so it must be deleted from my database too.

Please let me know if i am wrong...

Comment: My solution in a mobile app of mine was to get the id's of the first and last items retrieved from the rest api, and do a delete between range in the database before inserting them, this is easy, fast and any deleted records that were deleted are gone, takes one fetch call to the api and one delete statement to the local db. Personally I wouldn't store 2000 tweets, re-fetch as the user scrolls the timeline, and cache in the db a minimum if n hours etc...

Comment: @DWRoelands As per twitter's developer policy, you are actually required to keep your data up to date (eg. you are not allowed to show tweets that have been deleted or are otherwise no longer visible): https://developer.twitter.com/en/developer-terms/policy#3-c

Answer (score 0):

You can make the status lookup call wit map parameter set to true. It will return null for deleted or protected tweets. It is more reliable way when compare to map set to false, because many a times lookup call doesn't return tweets even if it is not deleted (esp. for retweets).